# Troubles with Return this and @override programing

Tags: java

So first I'm gonna post the code then ill explain my problems

```
import java.util.*;

class Loader
{
       protected int BucketSize;
       protected int bucket;
       protected int price;

   public void SetBucketSize(int b)
   { 
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("What Bucket Size (1-5)?");
       bucket = input.nextInt();

       while (bucket <6)
       {
         System.out.println("Enter valid Bucket Size(1-5)");
       }

          if (bucket == 1)
          {
             price = 100;

          }
          if (bucket == 2)
          {
            price = 200;
          }
          if (bucket == 3)
          {
            price = 300;
          }
          if (bucket == 4)
          {
            price = 400;
          }
          if (bucket == 5)
          {
            price = 500;
          }
        b =  price;   
        price = BucketSize;    
   }
      public void GetBucketSize()
      {
         return this.BucketSize;
      }

    @Override
    public void setRentalProfit()  
    {
      RentalProfit = (RentalRate * RentalDays);  
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "Tractor (Rental days = " + RentalDays + ", Rental Rate = " + RentalRate + 
        ", Rental profit = " +  RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID + BucketSize + ")";
    } 


}
```

Heres the errors :

```
Loader.java:46: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
         return this.BucketSize;
                    ^
Loader.java:49: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Loader.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
      RentalProfit = (RentalRate * RentalDays);  
      ^
  symbol:   variable RentalProfit
  location: class Loader
Loader.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
      RentalProfit = (RentalRate * RentalDays);  
                      ^
  symbol:   variable RentalRate
  location: class Loader
Loader.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
      RentalProfit = (RentalRate * RentalDays);  
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable RentalDays
  location: class Loader
Loader.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        return  "Tractor (Rental days = " + RentalDays + ", Rental Rate = " + RentalRate +
```

Things like RentalDays and other variables are in another class I'm just stuck on what to do here. I can't figured out why its telling me the return thisBucketSize is an incompatible type and also I'm not sure why its not finding the RentalDays and variables that i have in another class in same final. any help/tips would be appreciated

Comment: I advice you to learn Java syntax. You are doing return in a void method, using a variable with our declaring. Please read the compilation error one by one and fix one at a time.

Comment: In addition to that, it's often helpful to reduce the program to its smallest possible size, then fix all errors, expand it a bit, fix all errors, and repeat that until you're done. In this case, you could reduce `SetBucketSize()` to only asking the question, and then slowly expand from there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with "return thisBucketSize" is that it's in a method which has a void return type. The issue with the override annotation is that Loader doesn't extend our implement anything, so there is no superclass to override. The other issues appear to be undeclared variables.

As a side note, class names are usually uppercase while variables are lowercase.